# Running concurrent/parallel Db Functions/Procedures in Postgres plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, parallel-processing, transactions, plpgsql

I am mostly a Java programmer and we can easily run different methods or functions multithreaded or in parallel (simultaneously) by creating new/different Threads.

I recently was writing many Functions and Procedures for my Postgres database and utilizing the **Pg_Cron** extension, which lets you schedule "Jobs" (basically plpgsql Functions or Procedures you write) to run based on a Cron expression.

With these Jobs, as I understand it, you can have the scripts run essentially in **Parallel/Concurrent**.

Now, I am curious, without using Pg_cron to run db maintenance tasks, is there anyone at all in Postgres to write "concurrent" logic or scripts that run parallel, without using 3rd party extensions/libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is trivial: just open several database connections and run statements in each of them concurrently.