# Call same stored procedure to run parallel for a different parameter passed to each call

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

Consider a table containing a list of variables to be passed to a stored procedure's parameter.
The stored procedure (ex : call test(input_id);) has a set of logic which appends the transformed results to a column in a new table and this is required to run in parallel for multiple variable passed from the other table.

Example : Table T having a column contain 5 IDs 35,66,33,88,64

Objective to achieve is write a code to feed these IDs into stored procedure and trigger in parallel:

call test(35);

call test(66);

call test(33);

call test(88);

call test(64);

Comment: That is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69654054/6464308), but the answer was never accepted, so I cannot mark it as such.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . Hope this clears .
PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.38463