# Is there a way to force parallel run of a function in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

i have a function write in Plpgsql that does some thing like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(rowid integer,mytable regclass,parama integer, paramb 
integer)
RETURNS SETOF mytype
AS $$

BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM ' || mytable || 'WHERE foo = $1 and bar = $2' USING 
parama, paramb; 
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I then have another function that insert the result of myfunc in a table (that have the same columns as mytype)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myinsertfunc( mytable regclass,parama integer, paramb 
integer,desttable regclass, rowid_min integer, row_id_max integer)
RETURNS void
AS $$
BEGIN
    FOR rowid  IN rowidmin..rowidmax LOOP           
            BEGIN
                 EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO '|| desttable ||' SELECT * FROM 
myfunc($1,$2, $3,$4,)')
                 USING rowid,mytable,parama, paramb;
            END; 
    END LOOP;
END :
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have like thousand of thousand of insert to do so at this time i perfform like this :

```
open one session on my postgresql instance and run :
select myinsertfunc(tablea,parama,paramb,1,1000)

Open a second session on my postgresl instance and run 
select myinsertfunc(tablea,parama,paramb,1001,2000)

Open a third session on my postgresl instance and run 
select myinsertfunc(tabledest,tablea,parama,paramb,2001,3000)


And so on until i reach quite a bottleneck in term of CPU or I/O disk
```

I wonder how i could force myinsertfunc to do the insert in parallel using max of the hardware/software capacity rather than just wait for the previous insert to being finish to start a new one (i know that i asked it with a loop so i just get what i asked for...).

Thanks for your help !

PS: The job done by myfunc is far more complex that in my example and has to be done per rowid so the solution can't be "don't use loop in SQL it's not why it is designed for"

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69654054/6464308).

Comment: indeed ... is it then possible to open/close database connections automatically through plpgsql ?

Comment: Not really. You can have a look at PL/Proxy.